# try builtin credential first, then prompt for another

Tags: authentication, powershell, credentials

I want to query a server for, say memory

```
gwmi win32_freephysicalmemory -computername server1 -credential $cred
```

I know about get-credentials and also constructing an pscredential-object,
but i want to first try to query with my current credentials, and if i get unauthorizedexception ill prompt for new credentials with get-credentials.
this way i could run the script from either my workstation or some server (i dont use the same creds)

i think i initially need to feed $cred with my current credentials and then change it in the catchblock if it fails, but how do i dump my logged on credentials to an pscreential-object?

Comment: Tried to set $cred to [System.net.credentialcache]::DefaultCredential but since it returns an interface, im not sure if its possible to cast to a pscredential-object somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty`?

Are you using PS 3.0?
You can set of default parameter value using

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add('Get-WMIObject:Credential',[System.Management.Automation.P
SCredential]::Empty)
```

And, when this fails, you can look for the Credential Parameter.

Comment: Right on! exactly what i was looking for.. when i pass a cred-object to get-wmi as returned from Empty(), Powershell (or dotnet) seems to use my logged on credentials since the object is empty? or something, just as good.

Comment: `$creds = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty

try{
 Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName server -Credential $creds
}
catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]
{
 Write-Warning "Not Authorized"
 $creds = Get-Credential -Message "Give me other credentials"
}
finally
{
 "retrying...`n"
 Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName server -Credential $creds
}`